# GitLab Runner: Execute code on server after switching user without shell

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm trying to set up automatic deployment for a GitLab project. Once a change is merged into the development branch, the runner is to log into the server, switch to a different user, go into the web directory, and perform git pull followed by a few other tasks.

In case you're not familiar with GitLab runners, it's essentially just a temporary server (docker image) that executes whatever you need it to. I just use it to ssh into the client server to execute the commands that I have so far been doing manually for each deploy, or at least that's the plan.

Client server os is Ubuntu, I can only login as *user*, for which I have a sudo pw, and the *specific-user* owns the website.

So far I have been able to connect to said server via ssh and set it up so that *user* can switch to *specific-user* without having to manually enter the sudo password. But this is where it ends - I am unable to actually execute any commands as *specific-user*.

Here is my current code (.gitlab-ci.yml) after a lot of trial-and-error and even more googling:

```
deploy_development:
  type: deploy
  environment:
    name: development
    url: https://website.com
  script:
    - ssh -tt user@server
      "sudo su - specific-user -s /bin/bash &&
      whoami &&
      cd htdocs &&
      git pull origin development"
  only:
    - development
```

The GitLab runner output is as follows:

```
$ ssh -tt user@server "sudo su - special-user -s /bin/bash && whoami && cd htdocs && git pull origin development"
Warning: Permanently added 'server, ip' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
special-user@server:~$ 
...
```

With the three dots being animated, presumably showing that the terminal is waiting for input.

Note: If I do "ssh" or "ssh -t" instead of "ssh -tt" I'm still *user* even after using sudo su and therefore unable to execute any code as *special-user*.

What do I have to do to actually execute my code as the other user?

Answer (score 1):

As always - once you post it to stack overflow, you find the answer ..

This is how I solved it:

```
script:
    - ssh -tt user@server
      "sudo -u special-user -H sh -c
      'cd ~/htdocs &&
      git pull origin development'"
```